# Bootstrap Slider: cannot call methods on slider prior to initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I use the following bootstrap slider on my current project:
https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider

However, I get the following error, which I cannot explain:

`bootstrap-slider.min.js?ver=4.9.1:4 cannot call methods on slider prior to initialization; attempted to call 'getValue'`

I have several sliders there, I'll just give you an example with one.

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $sliders = $('.apd-slider');

    $("#AmazonPriceInteger").slider({
        id: "AmazonPriceInteger",
        min: 0,
        max: 5000,
        range: true,
        value: [0, 5000],
    });

    //The console doesn't trigger, when I change the sliders...

    $selects.add($sliders).add($checkboxes).change(function () {
        console.log("This doesn't even trigger");
        var hiddenItems = getHiddenItems();
        console.log(hiddenItems);
        updateVisibility(hiddenItems);
    });
}
```

HTML

```
<label for="AmazonPriceInteger">Preis (EUR)</label>
<div class="box--slider">
    <span>0</span><input id="AmazonPriceInteger" type="text" class="span2 apd-slider" data-slider-handle="custom"/><span>5000</span>
</div>
```

The funny thing is, this seemed to work all the time. I didn't change any of the code and then all of a sudden, it stopped working.

I had this problem before though and I thought I fixed it, which you can read here:
[jQuery Slider: cannot call methods on slider prior to initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47213059/jquery-slider-cannot-call-methods-on-slider-prior-to-initialization?noredirect=1#comment81375984_47213059)

This is the link to the project: http://www.maehroboter-guru.de/maehroboter-liste/

It's in German though. If you click on it, you just have to click on "Filter Einstellungen" to see the sliders.

Comment: Are you checking that the document is ready before calling? i.e. $(document).ready(function() { /* Your code */ });

Comment: Yes! The whole thing is in a $(document).ready(function () {}. I edit the code above to make it clear.

Comment: I'm trying to recreate it here: https://jsfiddle.net/50Lwa73y/1/
So far, it seems to work but I'm still investigating your site.

Comment: You may have an issue with $selects being returned before it was declared. I would try declaring var $selects, $sliders, $checkboxes; at the start of that "jQuery(document).ready(function(t) {});"

Comment: In fact, you seem to have a lot of locally used variables that seem to be applied globally. This may well be causing some issues, especially with generic terms like "values".

Comment: I think I did what you advised me to. It made it a tiny bit better. Now at least the console.log triggers, but the sliders still don't work.

Comment: Glad I could help a bit. There seem to be errors in the debug console but I haven't got enough to go off. Are you able to [debug the code](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/)?